# Adding application as contributor with Terraform azure

Tags: azure, terraform

Hi im currently working on trying to figure out how to assign an application as contributor within a specific resource group in azure with Terraform.
any working examples is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign a given Principal (User or Application) to a given Role with Terraform. You can use [azurerm_role_assignment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html) and Data Source: [azurerm_resource_group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/resource_group.html), [azurerm_client_config](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/client_config.html)

Example Usage, Create a built-in role as a contributor within a specific resource group.

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "primary" {}

data "azurerm_client_config" "test" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "test" {
  scope                = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.primary.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = "${data.azurerm_client_config.test.service_principal_object_id}"
}
```